# choose the elements from a set to form a group

Tags: group-theory

let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. supose $H$ is a proper subset of integers and $H$ is a group under addition that contains exactly $3$ elements from $[p,p+q,pq,q^p,p^q]$. we have to choose any 3 such that it forms a group under addition. i honestly don't know where to start. firstly for addition identity $0$ is not in the set.

> Also $<p,q>$=$1.Z$ so each element is in $H$??

Answer (score 2):

First, note that $p$ is the only prime divisor of $p$ and $p^q$ and $q$ is the only prime divisor of $q^p$. Also $p$ and $q$ are the only prime divisors of $pq$ and neither of them divide $p+q$.

By Bèzout's Identity, if we have any two coprime numbers in $H$ then we have $1\in H$ and therefore $H = \mathbb{Z}$ (which is not a proper sugbroup).

Therefore we can discard $p+q$. Out of the remaining $5$ elements $p$ divides $3$ of them and $q$ divides $2$ of them. We can see that the only selection of $3$ elements such that no two are coprime is $\{p,pq,p^q\}$.

---

It's worth mentioning that the subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ are exactly those of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$. In our case $H = p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: thank you! very helpful